# How can my eco-hippies build a taser to down a polar bear?

Tags: weapons, fauna, engineering, electricity, self-defense

I have some radical environmentalists as some of my characters. They don't want to kill *any* living thing, but they live in an area where the polar bear population is anomalously high, and attacks are frequent. They want to build a taser capable of stopping one in its tracks.

What would such a taser look like?

Comment: Tasers are no more reliable than bear spray.

Comment: @Alexander They don't care.

Comment: If polar bears are that common there, what are the eco-hippies using for a source of food? Seals?

Comment: Advanced, self-contained hydroponics facilities.

Comment: This kind of reminds me about a short story from late 80s or early 90s.  Someone made some dinosaurs from DNA (long before Jurassic Park) and some eco nutjobs decided to release the poor, helpless, unfairly caged, animals.  IIRC, two were eaten by the Alosaurus, one was treed (the survivor) by the triceratops and one was accidentally stepped on by the brontosaurus.  I think it was written by Alan Dean Foster but my memory is notoriously bad for certain details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your eco-hippies would have to create something truly gruesome.

Look at Edison's attempt to discredit Westinghouse and Tesla's DC current when he electrocuted Topsy the Elephant [(video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVD37OwcNPA) [(image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Topsy_elephant_death_electrocution_at_luna_park_1903.png) [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topsy_(elephant)).  That was a lot of current.

The ends of the taser would look more like harpoons and need really thick wires.  You need barbs like on a harpoon to keep the tips from coming out of the flesh of the polar bear.  Those barbs will leave flesh ripping gashes when they are removed.  Also, unless you have two eco-hippies (and some spares) who are stupid enough to run up to the bear with clumsy tethered spears, you will need something to fire them with some force.

You do realize that a taser doesn't knock people out (except on TV)?  All it does is make your muscles twitch too much to be used by conscious control and it hurts.  The result is that as soon as they stop torturing the polar bear and turn off the current (and the bear's muscles stop twitching), they will be facing a **very** unhappy polar bear who runs faster than them.

The reaction to their solution should be something like:  "And this is how they chose to die?"

Comment: "The reaction to their solution should be something like: 'And this is how they chose to die?'" Exactly what I'm going for here. Sane people that don't want to be attacked by bears either avoid contact or use a gun. These people might be sane by their own definition, but not by ours - they won't even move away from the bears.

Comment: KEY_ABRADE maybe they could build some kind of fortified electric fence? I think that could shock the bears without needing to go head-to-head with them. 

Glaciologists will carry rifles to the North Pole to defend themselves against polar bears, and even those likely won’t necessarily repel the bear, and that’s when you’ve got a distance for the bear to close. Even if a taser could work, there’s no way a human that close to a polar bear could even use it before getting mauled.

Comment: Wiki is wrong? - "Edison was never at Luna Park and the electrocution of Topsy took place ten years after the war of currents.[2]"

Comment: @MolbOrg Oh, say it isn't so!  :-)  I was just going for the picture which was much clearer than the video (and giving link credit to the site with the picture).

Comment: @MarkPrice That's why I mentioned spares for the people throwing the harpoons.

Comment: Was he or wasn't, eh, do not care) Poor Tipsy( - but in terms of look at a history and a story in that history - great you linked it, superb, it was an interesting read, especially that a pound of cyanide did nothing - what a times it were, eh

Comment: @MolbOrg yep.  Though it is true that Edison encouraged DC current in the electric chair to show how dangerous it is.  Also, I still wouldn't put it past Edison to do it 10 years later.  He was a vindictive SOB.

Answer (score 3):

## [Electrified Water Cannon](https://military.wikia.org/wiki/Electrified_water_cannon):

There's no guarantee this bad boy won't kill PEOPLE, but that's irrelevant. The voltage and current may require some adjusting to get right. I would go with a modified fire vehicle with water tank as the basis for the cannon. Get a hose firing high-pressure saline solution (you know, like salt water) and run a lot of power through it. Keep firing it at the bear until it can get up the gumption (assuming it can) to run away. No embedded barbs, and hopefully no permanent harm.

All the components would be available in an arctic coastal town (you know, like the setting for eco-crazies). I could even see how this design would evolve from attempts to repel the bears with fire hoses. A fire tanker truck, like those used to combat brush fires (or in places that lack fire hydrants), could be married to the water cannon of a fire engine (it might even be built that way). Fill it with salt water (possibly originally so it didn't freeze as easily). One in the arctic might have a heating system to prevent the whole thing from icing up.

I'm not even guaranteeing it would work, but it's the kind of thing someone trying to build a giant taser would design in the artic with available parts. There's dozens of saner, more effective, less dangerous (to both people and polar bears) ways to keep out the bears. Of course, REAL ecologists would say, "Fix whatever is causing the anomaly, and set the environment right." Better to use a tranquilizer gun, sedative baits, flash-bangs, bear repellent, mace cannons, shotguns with rock salt, avoidance strategies, sonic repellents, smoke grenades (likely with built-in capsaicin), truck-mounted glue cannon (biodegradable, of course), etc. Better to repel the bear than risk it getting hurt with a taser. Electric fences would also be extremely effective.

But if you have an ecologist/electrician/volunteer fire fighter who wants to make an anti-polar bear stun gun, this is how I would do it.